# Compute integral $ \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \frac{y}{1+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}^5}$.

Tags: real-analysis

I want to compute if exists $\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \frac{y}{1+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}^5}\,dx\,dy$ so I study absolute integrability on $\mathbb{R}^2.$

I use polar coordinates and I found $4\int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{r^2}{1+r^5} dr$.

This integral exists because $g(r)=\frac{r^2}{1+r^5} \sim \frac{1}{r^3}$ near $\infty$? Why is null?

Comment: Do you mean $4\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{r^2}{1+r^5} dr$?

Comment: @GiuliaB. The function is odd wrt y and even wrt x, hence the integral is zero. N. B. In your polar form $r$ goes from $0$ to $\infty$ as pointed out Lord.

Comment: If I want compute the same integrand function on $B((0,r),2r)$  I use the same method?